# JQueryUIHelpers().AutoCompleteFor - how to use JS Events to submit form on select

Tags: jquery, user-interface, asp.net-mvc-5, helper

I am using JQueryUIHelpers from GitHub. 
I am using AutoComplete to search and display results in a select list below the search box.
I want to submit the form immediately an item in the displayed list is selected.
My code is below.

```
            @Html.JQueryUI().AutocompleteFor(x => x.SearchForID, Url.Action("AutoCompleteSearch"), "SearchFor", null, 
                        new { id = "SearchFor", @class = "form-inline form-control", onchange="this.form.submit();"})
```

This is not working. I have tried using the onselect event but it fires when text in the search box is selected doh!

Your assistance with this would be appreciated.

Wee.

PS - could someone of reputation 1500 or above create the tag JQueryUIHelpers? 
:-)